# @color/black vs @android:color/black

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

As the title suggests, I noticed there were two options for black color, and that made me wonder, is there any difference between @color/black and @android:color/black when styling texts etc.? Is there a reason why those two exist separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@android:color/black` - this references to Android framework built-in value, which is unchanged and points on `#000000` color. Until Android folks won't make for us any joke in some OS release it is safe and reliable reference to use, in API since the beginning

`@color/black` - this points on your custom reference declared in your app. You can put in there any color in fact, thus in that way quick re-styling whole app. (btw. it's better to use location-naming e.g. `list_separator` or `fragment_background_default` for keeping this possibility) Or you can remove this entrance in `colors.xml` (most common) and then `@color/black` becomes "unresolveable" (app won't build)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, using the resources under @android: are those integrated by default in the android version the app is installed, so can change if the values are changed in newer android versions.

if you use the normal @color/ you are referencing your color.xml file, and no matter any change in the android version, this will always be the color you assign.

Comment: close, but afaik: _integrated by default in the android version the app is installed_ - this `int` in fact is "built-in" into app, is resolved with `targetSdkVersion` or `compileSdkVersion` during building (not shure, maybe mix). after app built it's static and will behave exacly same on every OS version, so depends on build targetting (before/after change in API), not on OS version of app installation

Comment: thanks for the clarification :D updating my db